# Mysqli array failing?

Tags: php, string, mysqli

I have a block of text and a preg_match_all sequence to create an array ($matches) from certain elements in the text.

I then look up a corresponding entry for each string in the first array using mysqli and receive a second array - ($replacement).

I want to replace the first array's position in the original text with the second array, re-finding the first array and naming it $arraytoreplace. This is the code I use:

```
$replacement = array();
$myq = "SELECT code,title FROM messages WHERE ID=?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli2->prepare($myq)) {
   foreach($matches[1] as $value) {
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
     $stmt->execute();
     // bind result variables
     $stmt->bind_result($d,$cc);
     if($stmt->fetch()) {
       $replacement[] = '<a href="'. $d .'">' . $cc . '</a>';
     }

   }
   $stmt->close();
}
```

If I use var_dump on the arrays before the str_replace like so:

```
var_dump($arraytoreplace);
var_dump($replacement);
```

I get:

```
array(4) {
         [0]=> string(3) "111"
         [1]=> string(2) "12"
         [2]=> string(4) "1234"
         [3]=> string(1) "0"
         }

array(4) {
         [0]=> string(5) "hello"
         [1]=> string(2) "hi"
         [2]=> string(3) "foo"
         [3]=> string(3) "bar"
         }
```

I then use str_replace to drop the second array into the first array's place in the original text.

Usually this is fine, but everything breaks once it hits the 10 string in an array mark.
Instead of `Text hello text hi` I'll get `Text 11foo text foo1` or something equally bizarre.

Any ideas?

Edit: The code used for replacing the arrays as follows:

```
$messageprep = str_replace($arraytoreplace, $replacement, $messagebody);
$messagepostprep = str_replace('#', '', $messageprep);
echo '<div class="messagebody">' . $messagepostprep . '</div>';
```

Comment: Do you mean, "once the arrays have 10 or more values"? I'm not sure what "10 string in an array mark" refers to...

Comment: show your replacement code. the db operations are pretty much irrelevant if you're mangling your strings later purely in PHP.

Comment: @Marc B - I'm confused, the replacement code is shown in the code block

Comment: @GordonFreeman - Yes, sorry. Once the array is made up of more than 10 strings. The error occurs at 10.

Comment: @user1428599: no, you show the OUTPUT of the code. show the actual code that DOES the replacing.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, right. Edited original question.

Comment: well, consider that your 'source' array has both `12` and `1234`. what if the `12` is replaced first? you'll end up with `34` dangling in the breeze, because it's no longer `1234`.

Comment: Ahh, right. Hadn't considered that. Could you think of a way around that?

Comment: @MarcB That was my thinking, but I couldn't get past the description. The solution is to use a regular expression that replaces based on the boundary of the numeric string (sic). Use `\b` as in `$content = preg_replace("/\b$key\b/i", $text, $content);`.

Comment: @GordonFreeman Sorry.. Could you put that into the context of my code for me? A little confused now.

Comment: In the context of your code, the second part of my answer would seem to the quickest solution to implement. Is there any reason why you can't pad your numbers with zeros?

Comment: There is, but it's extremely long to explain.

Comment: If you store HTML in your database, you're going to have a bad time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your getting partial replacements when a string of numbers is contained inside a longer string, i.e. `23` inside `1234`.

You need to do your replacements with a regular expression on the boundary of the search string. Something like...

```
$text = preg_replace("/\b" . $replace . "\b/", $value, $text);
```

Another possible solution would be to consider changing the values to replace so that they are padded with zeros...

```
Array(
    [0] => string(3) "0111"
    [1] => string(2) "0012"
    [2] => string(4) "1234"
    [3] => string(1) "0000"
)
```

...and make sure that your search strings are also padded with zeros, because `0012` will never be confused with `12` and accidentally found in `0123`.

Comment: That would make sense. Unfortunately the database cannot be padded with zeros in this case (long story) so using your first solution would probably be the answer. Where would I put that snippet (with relevant names) so it'd all work?